# IntelliJ IDEA Plugin dev library missing GSON

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm building my old IntelliJ IDEA Plugin using new IDEA version (2017.3), and it gives warning:

```
Warning:Kotlin: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: /home/ice1000/IDE/idea-IC-172.3544.35/lib/gson-2.5.jar
```

And errors:

```
Error:(4, 19) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: gson
Error:(29, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Gson
Error:(48, 24) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Gson
```

Seems that the GSON library is removed, but my plugin is running finely in the new version.
But I can't build my plugin now.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Removing the libraries from the project might help - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312518/610979